# Java ExecutorService - Creating a new thread but not starting it

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I came across below code snippet while reading `ExecutorService` section from book `Java 8 The complete reference`.

Below code snippet explains how `ExecutorService` works.

```
// A simple example that uses an Executor.

import java.util.concurrent.*;

class SimpExec {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(5);
        CountDownLatch cdl2 = new CountDownLatch(5);
        CountDownLatch cdl3 = new CountDownLatch(5);
        CountDownLatch cdl4 = new CountDownLatch(5);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        System.out.println("Starting");
        // Start the threads.
        es.execute(new MyThread(cdl, "A"));
        es.execute(new MyThread(cdl2, "B"));
        es.execute(new MyThread(cdl3, "C"));
        es.execute(new MyThread(cdl4, "D"));
        try {
            cdl.await();
            cdl2.await();
            cdl3.await();
            cdl4.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
        es.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {

    String name;
    CountDownLatch latch;

    MyThread(CountDownLatch c, String n) {
        latch = c;
        name = n;
        new Thread(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```

What I am not able to understand is the last line in the constructor of class `MyThread`.

The constructor of `MyThread` creates an Object of `Thread` using

> new Thread(this)

However, this newly created thread is never started by calling `start()` method. Also, according to my understanding `ExecutorService` creates and manages its own threads to run our `runnable` task. Then why is this `Thread` object being created in this case?

Comment: (a) The line you mention is a no-op so just remove it. (b) Why would one call a `Runnable` class `MyThread` and not, say, `MyRunnable`?

Comment: @assylias (a) I am confused then why is this line even a part of the example code. (b) Thats a sample code from the book, not my code ;)

Comment: (a) Only the author knows (b) I understand - I was just stating that it makes me question the book quality. But I haven't read that book so I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line:

```
new Thread(this);
```

is taking no effect on the execution of the code and you can removed without a problem...

the executor will create its own thread in order to execute the code

you can verify that this line of code is not taking effects by:

1. removing the line from the code (it will get the same result)
2. giving a name to the thread and debuggin `new Thread(this, "T: " + n);` you will see that no thread with such a name appears in the stack
3. you can cehck the source code of the ThreadPoolExecutor and verify that the method `private boolean addWorker(Runnable firstTask, boolean core)` is creating a new worker from the runnable you gave as parameter and from that  they do

--

```
w = new Worker(firstTask);
final Thread t = w.thread;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the confusion!